# Can't set CMake configuration parameters from Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I am trying to use the entire CMake workflow from Visual Studio. I created a folder with a `CMakeLists.txt` file along with the code, and Visual Studio magically builds and configures it with the parameters I specified in the `CMakeLists.txt` file.

However, I can't seem to configure the parameters that I am able to configure from the CMake GUI. I thought that the `CMakeSettings.json` file that VS creates when I "Configure" the build would help me override the default settings, but VS still builds with the default parameters, even if I change their values there and save it.

What is the correct way to set the build parameters from Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you could refer to the following docs:

[Configure and build with CMake Presets in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmake-presets-vs?view=msvc-160)

[Customize CMake build settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/customize-cmake-settings?view=msvc-160)

Comment: I solved by using the `CMakePresets.json` file instead as suggested there